# Are the words in the Lord's Prayer "Hallowed BE Thy Name" or "Hallowed BY Thy Name"?

Tags: lords-prayer

I was recently caught off guard when encountering a version of the Lord's Prayer that has it as hallowed-by; [the page](https://www.seekingvirtueandwisdom.com/st-maximus-the-confessor-blog-2-centuries-of-theology-and-lords-prayer/) goes so far as to cite Matthew 6:9-10, even as exactly none of the English versions [on BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/matthew/6-9.htm) translate it like that. A user on this site used this apparently novel version of the verse, as do plenty of webpages who's general purpose for doing so is to center deification/perfection Theologies. Is this simply a shoddy mistake on their part or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Young's Literal Translation has _hallowed be thy name_. Green's Literal Translation has _let be sanctified your name_. [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/6-9.htm) translates αγιασθητω as 'hallowed be'. αγιασθητω is the aorist imperative passive (third person singular) and 'hallowed be' is the correct translation.

Comment: This question would be better asked on [Bible Hermeneutics.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's probably just a typo.

Comment: The Bible wasn't written in English, originally.

Comment: In the King James Version of the Bible the text reads: ‘After this manner therefore pray ye: Our Father. who art in heaven, Hallowed be thy name.’ Matthew 6:9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's surely just a typo. The word in the original languages here is *hagiastheto* which is both passive and a third person imperative.  A third person imperative in English is something like this.

Who will clean the room?
Let Danny clean it!

Let here sounds a lot like giving permission in modern English.  We don't use 3rd person imperatives.  We use 2nd person (you) all the time:  *Clean it!*  We sometimes use 1st person plural (we) *imperatives:  Let's clean it!*  This is the same grammatical idea, but for a third pe)son (he/she/it) party.

A passive verb is one where the subject is the one receiving the action instead of doing the action.  So a third person passive imperative might be like this:

Let the room be cleaned!
i here s *hagiazo* which means "to make holy".  So what happens when we make that a 3rd person passive imperative?

Let it be made holy!

And the "it" here is *onoma sou* ... "your name" ... so *Let your name be made holy* ... but we have a special work for something that has beendin English made holy: hallowed.  **strong text**  So, we end up with

***Hallowed be your name.***